# Rx: Difference between CurrentThreadScheduler and ImmediateScheduler

Tags: c#, system.reactive

Can anyone please describe the difference between the currentThreadScheduler and ImmediateScheduler? For the below code, I couldn't see any difference it makes?

```
        var rates = new List<FxRates>()
        {
            new FxRates() {CurrencyPair = "USD/GBP", BidPrice = 2.01m, AskPrice = 2.00m},
            new FxRates() {CurrencyPair = "USD/Eur", BidPrice = 1.3m, AskPrice = 1.31m},
            new FxRates() {CurrencyPair = "GBP/Eur", BidPrice = .8m, AskPrice = .81m}
        };

        var observable = rates.ToObservable(ImmediateScheduler.Instance);//Change to CurrentThreadScheduler
        observable.Subscribe(
            rate => Console.WriteLine("ThreadId:{0}, IsBackground:{1}, CurrencyPair:{2}",
                Thread.CurrentThread.ManagedThreadId, Thread.CurrentThread.IsBackground, rate.CurrencyPair));
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With ImmerdiateScheduler, the action is executed immediately.
With CurrentThreadScheduler, it will be executed on the current thread but may be executed later : the action is added to a queue.

[CurrentThreadScheduler vs ImmediateScheduler](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/7f75482f-eff2-4938-9491-47fe870989e8/currentthreadscheduler-vs-immediatescheduler?forum=rx)

Comment: To clarify, when they say "current thread", are they referring to the source thread (where OnNext is called) or the subscription thread (where Subscribe is called?).  I think it means where OnNext is called, but am not sure.

Answer (score 12):

Someone asked me this the other day, and it motivated me to come up with a simple example. Consider the following code which schedules an action that:

- Schedules *another* action to write out `2` to the console
- Then writes out `1` to the console.

Here's the code:

```
var scheduler = Scheduler.CurrentThread;

scheduler.Schedule(() => {
    scheduler.Schedule(() => Console.WriteLine(2));
    Console.WriteLine(1);
});
```

So what's the output? Well, with the `Scheduler.CurrentThread` we get:

```
1
2
```

But if we swap for the `Scheduler.Immediate` we get:

```
2
1
```

Why? Well the `ImmediateScheduler` will execute the scheduled action on the current thread as soon as it is scheduled. In this case we see that even though we are mid-way through executing a scheduled action, the `ImmediateScheduler` will call in to the newly scheduled action straight away.

In constrast, the `CurrentThreadScheduler` will queue the action on the current thread and it will be executed when the currently executing action completes (and after any other queued actions, if there are any).

The `CurrentThreadScheduler` can be particularly useful in avoiding deadlocks as only one scheduled action will be executing at any given time, avoiding the nesting effect of the `ImmediateScheduler`. By the same token, it also avoids building up deep stacks.

Comment: +1 A picture (or code example) is worth a 1000 words.